# escaping and sanitizing input for custom widget form fields

Tags: widgets

Is there a better way to validate the form method inputs of a custom widget? I want to avoid to create a long list of control structure or variables. 
For eample here is the code I've used for a custom widget form method:

```
public function form( $instance )
  {
    $background = '';
    $title = '';
    $claime = '';
    $organization = '';
    $address = '';
    $phone = '';
    $email = '';
    $vat = '';
    $fb = '';
    $ig = '';

    if( $instance ){
      $background = esc_url( $instance['bg_image'] );
      $title = esc_attr( $instance['title'] );
      $claime = esc_attr( $instance['claime'] );
      $organization = esc_attr( $instance['organization'] );
      $address = esc_attr( $instance['address'] );
      $phone = esc_attr( $instance['phone'] );
      $email = esc_attr( $instance['email'] );
      $vat = esc_attr( $instance['vat'] );
      $fb = esc_url( $instance['fb'] );
      $ig = esc_url( $instance['ig'] );
    }
    ?>
    // html inputs here...
    <?php
  }
```

As you can see there are many variables that are escaped using the `esc_` functions of wp. I imagine a series of control structures with `if` and `else` for each variable, but I'm sure there's a better way? Any suggestion will be appreciated